# Determine User Input Contains URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a input form field which collects mixed strings.

***Determine if a posted string contains an URL (e.g. http://link.com, link.com, www.link.com, etc) so it can then be anchored properly as needed.***

An example of this would be something as micro blogging functionality where processing script will anchor anything with a link. Other sample could be this same post where 'http://link.com' got anchored automatically.

I believe I should approach this on display and not on input. How could I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to call a function on every match in PHP. You can for example use something like this:

```
<?php

function makeLink($match) {
    // Parse link.
     $substr = substr($match, 0, 6);
     if ($substr != 'http:/' && $substr != 'https:' && $substr != 'ftp://' && $substr != 'news:/' && $substr != 'file:/') {
        $url = 'http://' . $match;
     } else {
        $url = $match;
     }

     return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $match . '</a>';
}
function makeHyperlinks($text) {
    // Find links and call the makeLink() function on them.
    return preg_replace('/((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])/e', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
}

?>
```

Comment: A string with content like this, only part of the link will be href "http://t.co/39OosMgU" . In this case only http://t.co/39O will have a wrapper href, the rest remains outside.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a regular expression to match common URL patterns. PHP offers a function called [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) that allows you to do this.

The regular expression itself could take several forms, but here is something to get you started (also maybe just Google 'URL regex':

'/^(((http|https|ftp)://)?([[a-zA-Z0-9]-.])+(.)([[a-zA-Z0-9]]){2,4}([[a-zA-Z0-9]/+=%&_.~?-]*))*$/'

So your code should look something this:

```
$matches  = array(); // will hold the results of the regular expression match
$string   = "http://www.astringwithaurl.com";
$regexUrl = '/^(((http|https|ftp):\/\/)?([[a-zA-Z0-9]\-\.])+(\.)([[a-zA-Z0-9]]){2,4}([[a-zA-Z0-9]\/+=%&_\.~?\-]*))*$/';

preg_match($regexUrl, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches); // an array of matched patterns
```

From here, you just want to wrap those URL patterns in an anchor/href tag and you're done.

Comment: I don't agree. ;) It's way easier to use `preg_replace()` in combination with a function, since you don't have to worry about the position of the match anymore. Also, it's made for it...

Comment: Fair point. I guess I was assuming that since the input string is unknown, it's possible that we're dealing with multiple URLs to match. Having those matches kicked back in an array seemed easier to deal with for large input, giving us a bit of choice in how we deal with the matches.

Comment: True, you do have more choose if you put all matches in an array. But `preg_replace()` is shorter and it also supports multiple matches like `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just how accurate do you want to be? Given just how varied URLs can be, you're going to have to draw the line somewhere. For instance. `www.ca` is a perfectly valid hostname and does bring up a site, but it's not something you'd EXPECT to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this.

You will build a pattern that will match the part of your string that looks like a URL and format it appropriately.

It will come out something like this (lifted this, haven't tested it);

```
$pattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";
preg_match($pattern, $input_string, $url_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
```

$url_matches will contain an array of all of the parts of the input string that matched the url pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the host information.

```
<?php

$host = $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

 ?>


  <a href ="<?= $host ?>/post.html">Post</a>
```

Comment: How does this help the OP? He wants to linkify arbitrary user-provided URLS entered into a text field.

Comment: The post was tagged PHP so I assume he is using PHP.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. It is PHP. but his own server's name is useless for identifying OTHER hostnames/urls in user-provided data.