# Regular Expression HREF Selection Incomplete

Tags: php, regex

This is a followup from another post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984213/determine-user-input-contains-url).

Problem: links aren't been wrapped with HREF completely, meaning just part of the URL is surrounded with link tags. A function which detects links on a string.

If the string contains `http://t.co/thions43` it's only returning part `http://t.co/thi` within a link tag.

```
<?php

function makeLink($match) {
    // Parse link.
     $substr = substr($match, 0, 6);
     if ($substr != 'http:/' && $substr != 'https:' && $substr != 'ftp://' && $substr != 'news:/' && $substr != 'file:/') {
        $url = 'http://' . $match;
     } else {
        $url = $match;
     }

     return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $match . '</a>';
}
function makeHyperlinks($text) {
    // Find links and call the makeLink() function on them.
    return preg_replace('/((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])/e', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected while I tested it. It returns:
`<a href="http://domain.co/thions43">http://domain.co/thions43</a>`

Comment: I think the code is expecting more than one character domain name. A link like this will not be wrapped correctly http://t.co/Ec497Cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you have to make your regex case insensitive, also you can simplify :

```
return preg_replace('/((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,#%&~-]*[^.\'# !(?,><;\)])/ie', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
```

You could also use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and there're no needs for i flag:

```
'/((www\.|http|https|ftp|news|file):\/\/[\w.-]+\.[\w\/:@=.+?,#%&~-]*[^.\'"# !(?,><;\)])/e'
```

Comment: If the string contains and or ends with double quotes and the link is right before, it converts the two letters before the quote and the quotes to � The wrapped link looks like this http://t.co/vaLxVduA���

Comment: @Codex73: just add the double quote within the character class, see my update.