# Escaping double quotes in strings with regex

Tags: php, regex

This is a followup from another post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227919/regular-expression-href-selection-incomplete).

Problem: The code below works good with the exception of strings that contain double quotes which will render  strange characters

Sample string:

```
“Walter Isaacson http://t.co/vaLxVduA”
```

Rendered as:

```
“Walter Isaacson http://t.co/vaLxVduA���

t.co/vaLxVduA���
```

I believe the problem is in the regex. What could I try to make this work?

Code:

```
function makeLink($match) {
    // Parse link.
     $substr = substr($match, 0, 6);
     if ($substr != 'http:/' && $substr != 'https:' && $substr != 'ftp://' && $substr != 'news:/' && $substr != 'file:/') {
        $url = 'http://' . $match;
     } else {
        $url = $match;
     }

     return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $match . '</a>';
}
function makeHyperlinks($text) {
    // Find links and call the makeLink() function on them.
    return preg_replace('/((www\.|http|https|ftp|news|file):\/\/[\w.-]+\.[\w\/:@=.+?,#%&~-]*[^.\'# !(?,><;\)])/e', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
}
```

Comment: What is "preg_replace"?  Why are you passing a regex literal inside quotes?  And the function call?

Comment: @Pointy: Are you serious? `preg_replace()` is the PHP function for doing a regex replace operation, and regex literals have to be passed inside quotes in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is die unicode character `”`. When you add the `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), to treat every string as UTF-8, it works, but also catches the quote as part of the URL. You would need to exclude this quote also:

```
preg_replace('/((www\.|http|https|ftp|news|file):\/\/[\w.-]+\.[\w\/:@=.+?,#%&~-]*[^.\'# !(?,>”<;\)])/eu', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
```

But your regex looks kinda huge, I did a quick search for a URL regex and [found this](http://snipplr.com/view/2371/) one, it seems to work also, and don't need all the exclusions

```
preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@eu', "makeLink('$1')", $text);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The first regex didn't work but the second did.